# cordova android: How to specify a custom MainActivity.java

Tags: cordova

What is the correct / best way to install a custom MainActivity.java class for an android cordova build?

I have multiple client projects which all share the same custom base Activity logic, so have a common.MyActivity class which contains all that logic, and I need MainActivity to import and subclass that.

This is my MainActivity class

```
package com.mycompany.mobile.myapp1;
import com.mycompany.mobile.common.MyActivity;
public class MainActivity extends MyActivity { /* extends CordovaActivity */
    public MainActivity() {
        super("MyApp1:MainActivity");
    }
}
```

Ideally I would like to be able to do this via a plugin (the same custom plugin that installs the common logic) but the issue is, the appid is different for each project, and the plugin needs to know that in order to instal the class in the correct folder.

I tried passing appid in as a variable to the plugin but the  tag doesn't expand the variable, so doesn't work.

If I can't do it in a plugin, then perhaps this can be achieved in config.xml in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `after_plugin_install` hook to copy the custom `MainActivity.java` into place if it's not already there.

In `config.xml` add

```
<hook src="scripts/hooks/updateMainActivity" for="after_plugin_install"/>
```

In `scripts/hooks/updateMainActivity` essentially do

```
cp MainActivity.java platforms/android/com/src/yourcompany/mobile/*/MainActivity.java
```

It's not ideal, but it works.

It's not ideal because the hook runs every time any plugin is installed, regardless of platform, rather than just running when the custom plugin is installed.  It is also not ideal because really it should be the plugin that does this, but there doesn't seem to be any way to achieve this just in `plugin.xml`.

If I find a better way, I will update my answer.

Comment: so where do you place the new java file to be copied to the android project?